# Storing Account Data in Balances Pallet versus System

Tags: substrate

Substrate saves account data by default in `frame_system`. Although storage for account data exists in Pallet Balances also and it seems it's never used.

What is the reason behind this? And which one we should use?

Comment: This post may answer your question:
https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/712/29